# `++` - Operator on two Arrays returns ArraySeq when using type parameters

Tags: scala

I tried to implement a simple binary tree, and this is what I came up with:

```
object main {

  class Node[A]

  case class EmptyNode[A](value: A) extends Node [A]

  case class NonEmptyNode[A](left: Node[A], right: Node[A]) extends Node[A]

  def traverse[A](tree: Node[A]): Array[A] = tree match {
    case NonEmptyNode(l: Node[A], r: Node[A]) => traverse(l) ++ traverse(r)
    case EmptyNode(v: A) => Array(v)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val binaryTree =
      NonEmptyNode(
        NonEmptyNode(
          EmptyNode("He"),
          EmptyNode("llo ")
        ),
        NonEmptyNode(
          EmptyNode("Wor"),
          EmptyNode("ld")
        )
      )

    val output = traverse(binaryTree).reduce((a, b) => a + b)

    println(output)
  }
}
```

Now I am wondering why it does not work, telling me:

```
Error:(11, 62) type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.mutable.ArraySeq[A]
 required: Array[A]
    case NonEmptyNode(l: Node[A], r: Node[A]) => traverse(l) ++ traverse(r)
```

while when I fix `A` to be `String`, for example, it does work:

```
object main {

  class Node

  case class EmptyNode(value: String) extends Node

  case class NonEmptyNode(left: Node, right: Node) extends Node

  def traverse(tree: Node): Array[String] = tree match {
    case NonEmptyNode(l: Node, r: Node) => traverse(l) ++ traverse(r)
    case EmptyNode(v: String) => Array(v)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val binaryTree =
      NonEmptyNode(
        NonEmptyNode(
          EmptyNode("He"),
          EmptyNode("llo ")
        ),
        NonEmptyNode(
          EmptyNode("Wor"),
          EmptyNode("ld")
        )
      )

    val output = traverse(binaryTree).reduce((a, b) => a + b)

    println(output)
  }
}
```

resulting in "Hello World" to be printed.

Comment: Why don't you just use `Seq` instead? `Array` is a Java type, which can lead to some issues with implicits (as is probably the case here).

Comment: Also `case class EmptyNode[A](value: A) extends Node` should be `case class EmptyNode[A](value: A) extends Node[A]`

Comment: You're right, fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because nothing is known about the type `A`, an `Array[A]` cannot be constructed. Because it cannot construct an `Array[A]` out of two `Array[A]`s, it falls back to `ArraySeq` instead.

If you really want to build arrays, you must provide `ClassTag` for `A`:

```
object main {

  class Node[A]

  case class EmptyNode[A](value: A) extends Node [A]

  case class NonEmptyNode[A](left: Node[A], right: Node[A]) extends Node[A]

  import scala.reflect.ClassTag
  def traverse[A: ClassTag](tree: Node[A]): Array[A] = tree match {
    case NonEmptyNode(l, r) => traverse(l) ++ traverse(r)
    case EmptyNode(v) => Array(v)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val binaryTree =
      NonEmptyNode(
        NonEmptyNode(
          EmptyNode("He"),
          EmptyNode("llo ")
        ),
        NonEmptyNode(
          EmptyNode("Wor"),
          EmptyNode("ld")
        )
      )

    val output = traverse(binaryTree).reduce((a, b) => a + b)

    println(output)
  }
}
```

Prints:

```
Hello World
```

The reason why an `Array[A]` cannot be constructed without additional information about `A` is that `Array[A]` can have different runtime representations depending on the size of `A`: it will be different for booleans, integers, longs, or `Object`s. If you want to avoid having `ClassTag`s everywhere in your code, don't use the low-level arrays, use some truly generic collection instead.

Comment: Does `ClassTag` have runtime overhead? If yes, it might be easier to use boxed `ArraySeq`.

Comment: @VictorMoroz It's not entirely clear: runtime overhead *compared to what*? The problem is: without the `ClassTag` it doesn't run at all, so how do you compare that... The class tags are inserted by the compiler at compile time, and whether an array is constructed by `new` or using a `ClassTag` that shouldn't be such a big difference. However, the `ClassTag`s might lead to unboxing of type `A` here, and the result would be that the array construction is slightly slower, even though the resulting array is more compact (e.g. for `int`). I don't know. For `A <: AnyRef`, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: @VictorMoroz I wouldn't worry too much about the performance here. The much bigger problem is that the `ClassTag`s "infect" the entire codebase that wants to work with generic `A`s and use the `Node` class. If you would try to build a library around this `Node`-definition, you would have to add `ClassTag` on everything sooner or later, that's a much more serious problem than +- few percent of performance.

Comment: I can replace `Array` with `ArraySeq` and it will compile and run without `ClassTag`. I guess for primitives it will then create unnecessary heap objects, so it's probably slower and takes more memory.

Comment: @VictorMoroz In principle yes, but in the code in the question, the heap objects already *are* created, because `Node` is not `@specialized` for primitive types, so it will store bunch of heap objects anyway. Whether unwrapping those heap objects and saving them in a more compact int-array will speed things up: I don't know, would have to try it out.

Comment: Does this mean any class (that isn't a primitive) that an `Array` can be built from is a Subclass of `ClassTag`?

Comment: @MarkusAppel No, `ClassTag`s do not participate in any inheritance hierarchies in any interesting way, it's not about *subclassing*, it's about forcing the compiler to generate an implicitly supplied token of type `ClassTag[A]` so that you can instantiate `Array[A]`. The `ClassTag[A]` thingie essentially carries around additional information about class `A`, so that you can check `isInstanceOf`, call `new`, and create `Array[A]`. For example, `ClassTag[Int]` would know that an `Int` needs 32 bits, so that an array of right size can be malloced.